# Do people use QR codes?

Tags: mobile, interaction-design, qr-codes

I want to let people install a mobile app after visiting a physical shop. My first go-to was a QR code, but I was wondering if people actually use them. Should I give a second option? What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Is this only limited to app installation or also for utility within the app itself? For example, I have an IP camera that pairs in an app and the QR code on the camera itself makes for a great UX since I just scan the code from the app. If your question, is only about app discoverability, that answer might not be good for this question.

Comment: Yes, you definitely should always make the encoded information (e.g. the app URL) available in human-readable form as well. QR-code only is an antipattern that discriminates those who don't have a QR reader at hand.

Comment: You should also add the information as readable text because QR codes became a security risk: Labels with malicious QR codes were labelled on top of the original codes and naive customers got trapped.

Comment: The death of the QR code has been predicted before: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8139/is-my-suspicion-correct-that-qr-codes-will-be-a-short-lived-standard-with-littl?r=SearchResults

Comment: https://picturesofpeoplescanningqrcodes.tumblr.com/

Comment: What's your intended location? The answer is probably very location dependent. Belgium? Big city? Small city? Village in the middle of nowhere? Is wi-fi an option in the street of the shop?

Comment: WhatsApp still uses QR codes to connect a phone to a browser on a different device, so it's definitely not dead yet.

Comment: @PhillipW the assumptions in that question are simply wrong, even the OP states as such in a comment to the question.

Comment: Why has the title been edited?  The new title is more formally grammatically correct; but the old one was a perfectly good informal use of language, and much more colourful.  Sacrificing colour for formality seems a shame.

Comment: Only if you give me a compelling reason to do so. Is there a reason I cannot find your app in the app store without using the QR code? I would much rather be on my merry way and get your app when it's convenient for me rather than being forced to stop, unlock my phone, find the stupid QR app, scan the code, and realize that it's just a link to yet another half-baked app that probably just wants to send me alerts about "deals" or telling me "We've missed you!"

Comment: Your sign should read "Download our XYZ app today!" and below it can be a QR code that says "Scan this code to get app immediately."

Comment: @MonkeyZeus no one uses QR code alone. It always comes along with a human-readable way to access the same thing in case one doesn't have a QR code scanner or doesn't want to use the quicker way

Comment: Like MonkeyZeus says, I would pretty much _never_ scan an "unknown" QR code (e.g. for installing an app), partly because you don't know its provenance. However, I daily use one generated _by_ an app to pay for my morning coffee (the app is from a UK coffee/snack-shop chain and their tills have QR-readers).

Comment: @Mast That's a pretty niche use case, and one that is fully integrated (e.g. WhatsApp generates the code, and the app has built-in QR code scanning). It's actually far easier than having a user type in their number and then a verification code, etc. So while yes it may not be "dead" in the sense that it's unused, it's possible that it will die soon in the sense that it will fall out of popular use and only be used for niche circumstances.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Not *that* popular currently but might become so again in the future. In your case I'd look for an additional option if possible.

---

**Edit:** Because of RonJohn's comment and the many people who agreed, I decided to remake the charts in "true" form, so the numbers look less manipulative.

---

[Scanova.io](https://scanova.io/blog/qr-code-statistics/) cites a few surveys across the years and claims it's on the rise:

> In 2014, Adobe Systems conducted a study on QR Code usage over a period of three months. The study covered four countries—Germany, France, UK, and the US.

<sub>Official study chart:</sub>
[image]
<sub>Chart remade in Excel:</sub>
[image: Chart showing use of QR codes in percentages per country]

> According to a recent survey by Statistia, in the US alone, an estimated 11 Million households will scan a QR Code in 2020. This is an increase from an estimated 9.76 Million scans in 2018.

<sub>Official study chart:</sub>
[image]
<sub>Chart remade in Excel:</sub>
[image: Chart showing use of QR codes in millions of households in the US]

They also make a good point how it's widely used in a few big Asian countries, especially China:

> WeChat—which is predominantly used in China—made the nation obsessed with QR Codes in the last few years. The Chinese scan QR Codes to make payments, get information, authenticate themselves, avail offers, and for practically every other use case.

---

Personally, I'm not too convinced. I barely ever see QR codes being used (living in a western EU country), not by people I know and also not in public.

This [mediag.com](https://mediag.com/blog/the-rise-and-fall-and-rise-again-of-qr-codes/) article makes a good point about it:

> A lot of people hear “QR code” and think, “2011 called, and they want their marketing tactic back.” However, **they’re starting to plateau, and even make a comeback** since their huge dip in popularity in 2014-2016.

So, seems like they're not very popular currently but might become so again in the future? Hard to tell. But for your use case this means that it wouldn't be a bad idea to have an alternative to it (since not everyone might have a QR code scanner app installed).

---

### Real Life Example

Interestingly enough, after saying how I never see them here, I just received this in my mail today :)

[image]

This is a really good example, as you can clearly see how **two options are given**. As Bergi said in his comment under the question, the QR-link should be provided in human-readable form as well.

Comment: A very big point is the practical application they have/are used in in China. A fun anecdotal example is a streamer that showed one of the fancy Chinese vending machines on stream and a member of their chat paid for their item, which is something really only possible through QR codes because of their incredible fault tolerance

Comment: iOS 12+ has a built in QR reader in the camera.

Comment: Those two graphs are great examples of lying with graphs.

Comment: Do people not perceive a security risk with QR codes? Basically, the users have to trust that a QR code is legit and isn't going to send them to a malicious website, and they have no idea where it's sending them before they scan it.

Comment: @shoover: that's not a security risk with QR codes itself. It doesn't matter if you're visiting a site printed on regular text URL or QR, people need to exercise their trust-risk judgements on the site they are visiting based on where they got the address from.

Comment: @shoover most implementations give you a prompt first detailing the action.

Comment: @Chloe QR code detection has native support in the camera app on both iOS (since iOS 11) and Android (since Oreo, via Google Lens)

Comment: "I barely ever see QR codes being used (living in a western EU country), not by people I know and also not in public." - it's indeed interesting to see that, on the one hand, - as you say - one rarely sees QR codes being used (i.e. scanned) by people, yet on the other hand, they are virtually omnipresent (at least here in Germany) - no matter where you look in public spaces, QR codes are on store fronts, on company cars, in trains and buses, on ad posters, in areas with public wifi hotspots, etc.

Comment: @LieRyan If I visit a regular text URL, I can (1) verify it's https rather than http, (2) verify the domain (as long as there 's no i18n/unicode confusables spoofing).  A QR code is as unsafe as a URL shortener.

Comment: @RonJohn: Well, maybe. It's not enough to just look at the base of the Y-axis and assume the whole graph is a lie. You have to consider [the broader context](https://youtu.be/14VYnFhBKcY) to evaluate whether a given Y-axis is appropriate or not, which often means considering information not shown on the graph in the first place. In other words, lying with statistics is a property of the author's intent, not a property of the graph that you can just read off.

Comment: QR payments in the Japanese market are growing great.

Comment: @RogerSangheeGold check the China market: bigger population, and everybody uses WeChat Pay or AliPay

Comment: @Mark, typically browsers also show the destination of links. I think the biggest security argument against both QR codes and HTML links is a variant on gerrit's second point: if you type the URL yourself, you know that the `a` is the Latin letter U+0097 and not the Cyrillic letter U+0430.

Comment: If I might add, in Portugal some of the restaurants have loyalty programs where you can either say to them your phone number/tax ID or scan a QR code from the restaurant associated app. We also have an app which is directly attached to our banking system that allows people to register and use the app to scan the QR code from the payment terminal to pay whatever they are buying (akin to other apps, but we can argue that this one is somewhat safer)

Comment: Your second chart wasn't remade properly - it shows 2018 as 7.76 instead of 9.76.

Comment: @gerrit If the pure act of visiting a url compromises you, you need a better browser. It's been standard practice for a while to only allow base permissions in browser tabs, with explicit requests to use other apis (location, microphone). verifying domain gets you less than you'd hope as well - the site of the store you're at might look like `exampleStore.com` but the malicious is at `exampleShop.com`; the only thing that'll help you with that is maybe the certificate, common sense/skepticism, or talking with the actual owner. Plus, all URL shortening is equally insecure.

Comment: @Delioth There's more types of threats than browser insecurity.  Perhaps after seeing the address I don't want to visit (if it looks like it might be NSFW or NSFL).  URLs including domain names matter.  I agree that all URL shortening is equally insecure, that was exactly my point (and QR codes being one type of URL shortening).

Comment: @gerrit In that case, even seeing the domain doesn't help you- the context is the important part. If you were unaware of the SE network, you can't really glean much info out of the name. Is it a place where people exchange stacks? Why so many subdomains, what is "ux" and why do people have stacks of it/them? The same applies to many sites - even a link to a sub-reddit or a facebook page can really easily be NSFW/L, even if a majority of the site is fine. Thus context matters (nondescript poster in a gentleman's club vs colorful mascot poster at a playground) probably more than the actual name.

Comment: @Spitemaster Good catch :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation!

Comment: I see the increase in usage of QR codes during this Covid-19 pandemic.

Example: Many of the restaurants are now only use the QR code for taking the order instead of providing a printed menu.

Answer (score 14):

In the US and Western Europe it's not used much. The stats are actually quite dismal. I see very few applications generating interest in QR codes. Skiing and hiking trails where one doesn't need to take off ones gloves is a niche-market exception.

On the other hand QR codes are really big in China, Hong Kong, Taiwan, Japan and Korea so if your market has a lot of East-Asian customers, especially East-Asian tourists, then I would include QR codes in all promotional material.

For example I put a QR code on my business card. It links to my website. I think of it as a stamp - analogous to stamps used with wax back in the day to authenticate ones signature; or like the red-ink stamps used in China, Japan, Korea.

In the US people look at my card and they go - "hey, looks good." It's perceived more like artwork, as an icon. I've given out 100s of cards at Meetups and am unaware of anyone going to my site via the card.

However, when I was in China the perception was much different. A large percentage of people took out their phones - on the spot - and scanned the QR code. I was so glad that I had updated my site before travelling.

The perception, the awareness, the comfort level regarding QR codes is far different in other countries and other cultures.

Comment: "and am unaware of anyone going to my site via the card" - does that say a lot about QR code usage as such? IMHO, the default content of a QR code *on a business card* is a VCARD entry, *not* a URL. I have scanned plenty of QR codes from business cards to add the respective data to my contacts, but had I ever encountered a website link instead of a VCARD in there, I don't think I would have opened it, as visiting a website is usually not my intended goal when scanning the QR code from a business card.

Comment: You raise an interesting point regarding the VCARD v URL.

Comment: in Vietnam QR codes are everywhere, just like in East Asian countries

Comment: China is likely to export more of "its thinking" as it moves from building less stuff subcontracted to Western Brands and starts to push more of its own brands onto global market - with associated documentation.

Answer (score 8):

I've actually done a fair amount of work with QR codes in the past.  It all depends on their implementation.  If you simply slap a QR code on a poster - not so helpful.  If it has a purpose and an incentive - people WILL scan them.  They are widely popular in some countries.  Basically - you've gotta give someone a reason to scan it.

Comment: Could you flesh this out a bit? What is enough of an incentive for people to scan the code? Is a QR code on a poster with a caption saying to scan it for more information "simply slap[ping] a QR code on a poster" or is it "a reason to scan it"?

Comment: I guess it depends. I'd say a use case like you've suggested would be valuable, for instance, in real estate.  If you were to scan a sign or one-pager in a window.

From a marketing standpoint you could 'scan to win' (which would bring you to a sign up page to solicit subscribers).

It's important to remember that QR codes are a mobile technology, so they should be implemented accordingly.  Does that help?

Comment: Two examples I’ve seen where QR codes get used: (1) In Pokemon Go to become “friends”, one person brings up their code and the other scans it.  (2) The local bus stops all have QR codes, scan one to find when the next buses will arrive.

Answer (score 7):

Also - you can customize / brand your QR codes to make them more visually intriguing – so long as you build in around 30% error correction. Here's a couple of examples one some I did (way back in the day).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure I'd ever recommend deliberately corrupting QR codes, but those really are done attractively!

Comment: These may look attractive, but I'll bet most people won't recognize that this is a QR code if they just see it on the street without any prompting even if they know what QR code is.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question of whether people use QR codes or not, although creating a more attractive or engaging design might help improve uptake.

Comment: While these certainly look interesting, actually scanning these would be the last thing I'd try. Exception might be the one in the top-right, which is the only one that looks like a well-formed code, but even then I might do so out of curiosity whilst bored, rather than actually trying to find some contact information / app / etc. Perhaps good for some viral marketing, but when usability is concerned, I feel this is a miss.

Comment: For usability, maybe not? but in term of engagement, I think these are a win - the viewer gets to feel good about spotting the qr code, if nothing else.  It engages their brain, which then means that they are engaging with the ad.

Comment: Yes, these need to be used as part of a bigger strategy.  As mentioned in another comment 'simply slapping a QR code on a thing' won't do you any favors.  They need to be driven by a purpose and provide some sort of incentive.

Also, this isn't 'corrupting' anything.If you scan these, they scan flawlessly - or I wouldn't have made them. To note; These are all years old an no longer point to anything existing. But you can at least scan them to see their accuracy. They should all be built with substantial error correction. So if a bird poops on it, or a paper gets folded - they still work.

Answer (score 5):

You should have a QR code, whether on screen or paper. It is important to note that both Android and iOS come with default QR readers. QR code is the easiest way to pass a URL. Unless your application is on the App Store, it will be difficult to get to the application download page without a QR code.

Comment: In my (limited) experience, over a number of years and Android devices, I haven't come across a default QR reader.

Comment: https://medium.com/turunen/simple-way-to-scan-qr-codes-by-android-without-downloading-app-4bd7693d2b5b

Comment: @DanGetz [Google Lens](https://lens.google.com/) is getting integrated to various Android devices, and it can handle QR codes.

Comment: among devices that I've used, only some Moto G phones have built-in QR code scanner. But I don't care about whether it's installed by default or not because one of the first apps that I install in a new phone is always a QR code scanner. QR code is so common that it's hard to get by without a scanner

Comment: Nevertheless the bulk of the population don't know this, I doubt they have the reflex to open Google Lens to scan QR codes

Comment: "...both Android and iOS come with default QR readers" really needs a source.

Comment: @hashim https://www.qr-code-generator.com/guides/scan-qr-code-android/ ,
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208843
Keep up with the times.

Comment: None of the links you provided source the claim you made, and the very first paragraph of the very first link you gave disproves it: "Despite this, still not many Android devices have a built-in QR Code reader." Not only did you fabricate a claim, not only are you doubling down on it despite having absolutely no evidence, you couldn't even go to the effort of reading the first paragraph of your intended "evidence".

Comment: @Hashim Did you check the latest Android version? Come back once you do it. Or read something about that. I have tested on both and they work.

Answer (score 2):

Just yesterday I used a new Amazon feature where I bring an unpackaged item to be returned to the UPS Store, show them a QR code, and be on my merry way. It was incredible.

I'm seeing more and more QR codes finally make their way into the consumer space. I would say it's a pattern that is gaining popularity and that more "civilian" users will continue to become comfortaBLE WITH.

Comment: As long as the user doesn't scan the QR code themselves, but just hands it over to another party, I'm not convinced this allows for any statement about QR codes. After all, Amazon could just as well give you a code number or some other form of visual encoding, all else equal - the consumer doesn't have to be aware or think about what a QR code is or how to use it. They are just given *something*, really *anything*, by Amazon that they have to show at the UPS Store.

Comment: That's a very good point. The cases where QR codes are useful are when you receive the code and scan it somewhere like a movie theater, UPS Store, or Whole Foods.

Comment: Not sure whether I got you right there - IMHO, the cases where QR codes are useful to users are when you receive the code and scan it with your device to save the trouble of typing something long (URL, wifi password, etc.). The cases you listed can make use of QR codes, but could just as well use something else without changing the effort from the user's perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely I would go with QR Code. But I will also show them icon and name of the app; and a website. On website you could have a link for ios/android app.
The people who use QR code will find it painless to scan and reach the intended app whereas its a hassle to go to website, or app store to install app, too many taps.
Showing them icon boosts the user(who use qr code) confidence that they landed on right place at the same time give other people option to find your app.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should provide multiple options that people are likely to have, and let them choose. That might include:

- URL (if it's dead easy to remember/type)
- App name (so they can search for it in an app store)
- QR code
- Twitter handle for the app or your shop (then a link in your bio)

Aim for flexibility without too many options - three is probably enough. Maybe even get some business cards printed with the same info on so they can take it with them for later, if they don't want to mess around with their phones right there.

Regarding usage, I don't see them used day to day. However, whenever I make a poster for a conference I always put one on that links to a PDF of it. Seems to be well appreciated and it's getting more common.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fact that even Chrome support a feature to provide a QR code for a web page instead of using links suggests that it is popular enough that it is accepted by just about everyone in the world now.

[image]

In many countries (like China) QR codes are already part of the normal day-to-day life as far as online activities and digital transactions go. For other countries, the changes introduced as a result of the pandemic has meant that digital ways of transacting are more acceptable and encouraged.

Suffice to say, compared to when the question was first asked, it is definitely used and accepted by the public in general.

Answer (score 0):

OH! I should also note that by adding a QR code to your print material, you can actually build in metrics you wouldn't otherwise have.  Since it uses a URL you can track all sorts of information (user location, device, number of scans, user pathways - all the usual).  Another important reason why you want to put practices in place that will incentive your audience to actually scan.

Comment: You should update your original Answer with this extra information rather than playing your answer across two Answers.

Answer (score 0):

A QR code technology can be said as an updated version of Barcode technology.QR code can be easily generated with QR code generator and it can be scanned via smartphone or 2-d scanner. But how can QR code be used in business?
Business Cards
[image]

In this modern generation, QR codes are the successors to barcodes which have gained popularity in recent years. There are more than a few reasons that are why QR code is better. QR code is versatile, it can be used for anything and everything, scan QR code and store information. There are several big brands who are utilizing asset tracking via QR code. Therefore, it proves that [**asset tracking**](https://www.assetinfinity.com) is successful with the QR code assistance.

QR code is more than just asset tracking. QR code is used to track more than names and prices of products, this will include information as serial number, part number, lots and dates, and other data. A QR code system is meant to serve you in the best and easy way.

You can manage, maintain and track your inventory in the best possible way. Implement it as soon as you can and track your inventory effectively and efficiently. QR code [**inventory management**](https://www.assetinfinity.com/blog/incidents-avoided-with-asset-inventory-management) is easier to handle and work with because the QR codes are typically easy to read through mobile phones and they don’t require the bulky hand-held scanners to read them.

Answer (score 0):

How would you deliver a QR code to a person *after* they visit a shop? That seems to be a scenario which requires more thought in that you must somehow remember some details of each person that enters and exits the shop in order to communicate with them, then send the QR code to them (doing so digitally would necessitate a QR scanner that can scan local image files, not all do that) or have them go to the QR code (inherently impractical).

I strongly encourage you shift your approach to one whereby you seek to have each store visitor use the QR code *while instore*. Even if it is on the backside of the entrance doorway for them to see as they leave (though, you could cause congestion on the entrance by placing a QR code there).

To decrease friction on whatever mobile platform the visitor uses, aim to provide the features of Firebase Dynamic Links either using Firebase Dynamic Links, a similar 3rd party service, of implementing your own logic on a web application that can forward to the appropriate store listing if the visitor does not already have the app installed.

As for a second option, your aim is to have the visitor install a mobile app and I assume that that app is the official app of the store: advertise the benefits of the app within the store and make the call to action in such advertising be a search term that has a very high chance of yielding the target app towards the top of the search results for whatever mobile platform store the visitor prefers. That way you arm the visitor's memory with the information necessary to search and find your target application ad-hoc, after they have left the store and in the case they overlook or decide against using the QR code mechanism.

My experience with QR code usage in China was:

- QR codes were generally placed near the cash register/checkout point.
- Sometimes QR codes were placed near entrances or on tables.
- Colleagues would utilise QR codes and pay using WeChat without my noticing, as I fumbled to find the correct change to pay with.
- Never did a QR code open a website, rather they would deep-link into WeChat.

Since many people are offering extra information about the proliferation of QR code usage worldwide, it seems that emerging markets in South-East Asia believe that standardisation in QR codes for payments is necessary: Malaysia, Singapore, Indonesia, and Philippines have each introduced national standards for QR code payments: https://www.opengovasia.com/a-commitment-to-grow-e-payments-in-the-philippines/